# Facing ant-design form validation issue on production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, antd, ant-design-pro

Basically, I am facing ant-design form issue on my production environment recently, previously it was working as expected. Validation only works when I run `NPM start` command on my local. If I use `NPM Build: serve` then facing the same issue on my local as well.

**Showing this error on the console when I perform validation task.**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at  createBaseForm.js:369

I tried to update all my NPM Packages along with mn NPM and node version as well, after facing this issue.

```
<FormItem>
   {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
      rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input username!' }],
      })(<Input addonBefore={<i className="iconfont icon-user" />} 
         size="large" placeholder="Username" /> 
   )}
</FormItem>
```

It's not showing me an error message which is used in rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, the error was caused by `lodash.memoize` and `lodash.paths` not loading in webpack build, as I was using `lodash-webpack-plugin` to reduce the bundle size.

Lodash features removed by default: [link](https://github.com/lodash/lodash-webpack-plugin#feature-sets)

Solution was to opt in to required features.

```
new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin({
    'memoizing': true,
    'paths': true
});
```

**Edit:** `antd` is using `rc-form` which in turn uses `lodash` to set errors.

Comment: what if I have not used lodash in my project ?

Comment: @HeratPatel What is the issue?

Comment: In production version it is not showing error. 
It populates error and working fine but errors are not showing at all.
so to resolve that I added extra props in <Form.Item>, `validateStatus` and `help`, and it works, but before it was working without adding extra props.